# Subquery in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, subquery

I've found a few similar topics so I'm sorry if this is kind of a repost but I'm trying to write this query in Eloquent using Laravel so I can paginate but frankly its confusing me..
Can anyone give a hand?

Here's the query:

```php
$results = DB::select(
    'SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE id IN '.
    '(SELECT ticket_id FROM working_on WHERE user_id ='.Auth::user()->id.
    ' AND NOT state=0 AND NOT state=2)'
) -> orderBy("id", "desc") -> paginate(3);
```

Which returns an error: "Call to a member function orderBy() on array" since its not written in Eloquent style.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `select` wrong. The `select` method accepts column names as parameters. It would also be best if you didn't use raw expressions because by doing that, you lose Laravel's escaping. Instead, you should leverage Laravel's query builder.

It should look something like this:

```php
DB::table('tickets')
  ->select('*')
  ->whereIn('id', function($query) {
    $query->select('ticket_id')
      ->from('working_on')
      ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
      ->whereNotIn('state', [0, 2]);
  })->orderByDesc('id')
  ->paginate(3);
```

By the way, the first `select` is redundant because `*` is the default value.

Also, consider querying the `Ticket` model directly instead of the database table or creating a `WorkingOn` model and using it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$results = Ticket::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('state','!=',0)->where('state','!=',2)->orderBy("id", "desc")->paginate(3);
```